# How to represent Spring ApplicationContext content

Tags: spring, architecture, uml, document

I was searching if there is a standard way to represent graphically spring ApplicationContext(content, parenty,...), like UML for class diagramm.

I found nothing on the web about this. So if you have any informations about this kind of representation, can you please share it ?

if some one have to do this which choice did you do ? why ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Which IDE do you use, with STS you can preview all beans in your application context as an UML diagram.

Comment: i use eclipse sts and i know this feature .but I want make a representation without any code behind, i want a way for conception and not for retro ingeneering

Comment: To simplify, ApplicationContext is just a container of beans (= instances of classes) so you can modelize your application as you want with any UML tool

Comment: so you will represent a Spring Context as an instance with link to parent instance ? but how to represente custom annot ; difference between instance refered by name or class ? component and services ?

Comment: I'll represent an ApplicationContext as a box which can contains other boxes (in case we have other contexts). And in each context (box) I'll have beans (I don't understand what do you mean by 'custom annot') which may or not be related each others